# Non-vandermonde functions $f:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}^n$ that always give a basis of ${\mathbb R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

A theorem says that $n$ vectors of the form $F(x) = (1,x,x^2\ldots,x^{n-1})$ always form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^n$ for $n$ different choices of $x$. Are there other interesting fundamentally different functions $F:{\mathbb R} \to {\mathbb R}^n$ with explicit parametric formulas, which have the property that for any $n$ different choices of $x$, the vectors $F(x)$ form a basis of ${\mathbb R}^n$?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'd call this "fundamentally different", but an interesting class of functions with a family relation to the van der Monde function is

$$F(x) = (e^{\lambda_1 x}, e^{\lambda_2 x}, \ldots, e^{\lambda_n x})$$

for distinct $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. It was shown in the course of this [MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118225/how-to-show-a-certain-determinant-is-non-zero) that this gives a basis for distinct $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$. Some explicit formulas were worked out by Darij Grinberg in his answer.

A search term which might guide you to further study is [alternant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternant_matrix). Such crop up for example in the study of Schur polynomials (for which explicit formulas have been extensively developed).